# Displaying text from SQL DB?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm just making a generic homepage but the difference is that the text on the page can be dynamically changed from the SQL DB using asp.net. Is there a Server Controls or an object that I can call that does this?

Comment: you need to implement a CMS in some way. There is no "control" to do this

Comment: search for how to read from database in asp.net

Comment: Thanks I'll do a search on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Labels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and set their `Text` value server-side:

**.aspx**:

```
<asp:Label Id="genericText" runat="server" />
```

**.aspx.cs**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check for initial page load.
    if (!IsPostBack)  
    {  
        // Grab some text to display.
        var content = (from p in myPageContent 
                       where p.PageNum == 1 
                       select p.Content).FirstOrDefault();

        // Load the content in the label.
        genericText.Text = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'll try that too.